# Autocomplete in bash, entering a space after any word

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I am writing a script to automatically augment command line arguments and everything works correctly, except for one thing. There are arguments that can consist of any number of any characters. When entering such an argument and pressing `<TAB>` I want the auto-complete mapping not to be done, instead just a space is added. Is it possible to do this?

Example:

```
$ script --method account/login aaa<TAB>
$ script --method account/login aaa<there_is_a_space>
```

So I use autocomplete for the arguments `--help`, `--method`:

```
  if [[ ${COMP_CWORD} == 1 ]] ; then                                     
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "--help --method" -- ${INPUT_ARG}) )    
    return 0                                                            
  fi
```

Can we make it so that for the argument "aaa" and any other character set, a space is just substituted, as if a match was found?